# How do I find the corresponding data in a 2D array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, 2d

I have a function that is returning price data to get the value of Bitcoin that uses Fetch API.

It is returning lots of arrays like so:

[1626307331537, 0.13854989964006934]

[1626310904101, 0.13710451247978309]

[1626314511945, 0.13589339336495737]

[1626318225092, 0.1372589802252777]

[1626321776129, 0.1375833005893342]

[1626325283955, 0.13800354086236513]

[1626328902533, 0.13836134131380867]

[1626332594721, 0.1343159833901

[image]

How do I return the corresponding value if I search by the timestamp (first part of the 2d array) for example 1626332594721 should return 0.1343159833901

Answer (score 1):

Here's a little function. It will return zero when there's no match found.

```js
let coins = [
  [1626307331537, 0.13854989964006934],
  [1626310904101, 0.13710451247978309],
  [1626314511945, 0.13589339336495737],
  [1626318225092, 0.1372589802252777],
  [1626321776129, 0.1375833005893342],
  [1626325283955, 0.13800354086236513],
  [1626328902533, 0.13836134131380867],
  [1626332594721, 0.1343159833901]
]

const findCoinFromTS = ts => {
  let f = coins.find(e => e[0] === ts);
  return f ? f[1] : 0;
}

console.log(findCoinFromTS(1626332594721));
console.log(findCoinFromTS(1626332594721000));
```

Comment: Is there a reason you define `f` before assigning it a value instead of assigning it on the same line you declare it?

Comment: @AsyncAwaitFetch - nope, not sure why I did that. Updated. Thx

Answer (score 0):

This should be like

```
let result = Array.filter(item => {
 return item[0] === "1626332594721";
})[1];
```

Item[0] is the array you iterate through and you get the second item which is
the Bitcoin value